# Disable permanently Ubuntu 19.04 drawer folder

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, 19.04

I'm trying to get rid of folders in Ubuntu 19.04 application drawer.

I tried with this command `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children []` but it only works temporarily until a reboot is performed.

After rebooting folders are back again.

I added that command in startup applications so that it is executed once system is powered up but it only works for a few seconds because it seems like ubuntu resets folders at startup and my startup command is executed prior its and the effect is brief.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Workaround***

Seems that the schema `org.gnome.desktop.app-folders` with the key `folder-children` is resetting after a unpredictable time with its own..

I have tried to reproduce the issue after running the below commands and yes there is a Issue..

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "[]"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children '@as []'
```

they are reset after a reboot or at a unpredictable time

So the only way I found is to lock this key with below steps..

1. Create a text file profile named `user` in `/etc/dconf/profile` directory with below content in it.

Content:

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

[image]

2. Create a Directory `local.d` in `/etc/dconf/db`
3. Create a Directory `locks` in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d`
4. Create a text file with the name `00_app-folders-children` with below content in the Directory `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks`

Content:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children
```

[image]

5. make sure the key is set as per your wish and then to lock it run `sudo dconf update`
6. Logout and Logback in to make the changes to effect..

Now you can check by running below commands

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "[]"
The key is not writable
pratap@i7-4770:~$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folder-children '@as []'
error: The operation attempted to modify one or more non-writable keys

Usage:
  dconf write KEY VALUE 

Write a new value to a key

Arguments:
  KEY         A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
  VALUE       The value to write (in GVariant format)

pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

Also GUI way with Dconf-Editor will not allow any changes to this key..

[image]

References:

https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf-lockdown.html.en
https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/3.8/dconf-profiles.html.en

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the `dock` (normally on the left side of your screen), then just right-click on the folder that you wish to remove, and select `Remove from Favorites` in the contextual menu.

Comment: I'm talking about [this](https://cdn.zillowtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Ubuntu-19.04-GNOME-3.32.jpg).