# Unable to create folder in gnome shell

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, desktop-icons

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my desktop. I was trying to group the apps listed in gnome-shell and I succeeded with the drag and drop features provided by gnome-3.36, but by doing so mistakenly I have edited the name of a folder to "KiCad". The same folder had an app named "KiCad" and from that time onward with each boot the the gnome-shell loads the default page with one group "Utilities" If I create a new group, in the next restart the same is getting deleted.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Hi.. It means are you loosing all your apps in the group KiCad you created?

Comment: I am loosing the group folder KiCad where I had kept the related apps. All the apps inside the folder are becoming un-grouped after a restart. This is happening for any group I create after that event. If I create a new group that is alive until I shutdown the system. In the next boot the default group i"Utilities" is forming.

Comment: For example, I have installed 2 web browser chroam and firefox when create a group "internet" and kept both the browsers in it, it was forming and was working perfectly, but in the next boot, the folder "internet" was getting deleted and the contents of that folder was available in the gnome-shell like other un-managed apps.

Comment: Ok, seems its a bug.. a similar one is here.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1146332/739431

Comment: the similarity is that the settings related to the gsettings key is overwritten or reset after a reboot.. but in your case locking the app folder is bit overkill.. If your folder and the apps inside it are fixed.. then you can try that workaround..

Comment: I agree with PRATAP  that this likely is buggy behaviour. Can you not delete the folder Kicad then start again grouping the apps and making sure you do not name the folder like the application inside?